# JavaScript inheritance not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

What are the details why `pe.getName()` is working and `pe.getSalary()` is not?

```js
var Employee = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Employee.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

var PermanentEmployee = function(annualSalary) {
  this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
}

PermanentEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
  return this.annualSalary;
}

var employee = new Employee("Mark");

PermanentEmployee.prototype = employee;

var pe = new PermanentEmployee(5000);

document.write(pe.getName());
document.write(pe.getSalary());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing this later in your code

```
PermanentEmployee.prototype = employee;
```

you might override this

```
PermanentEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function()
```

Try this instead:

```js
function Employee(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Employee.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}
   
function PermanentEmployee(name, annualSalary) {
  Employee.call(this, name);  // calling parent's "constructor"
  this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
}
PermanentEmployee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype); // setting "inheritance"
PermanentEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
  return this.annualSalary;
}
var pe = new PermanentEmployee("Mark", 5000);

console.log(pe.getName());
console.log(pe.getSalary());
```

Comment: but what is actually happening behind the scenes of my code.. Please explain.

Comment: you reset _ _proto_ _ ref. of `PermanentEmployee` object to `employee` object and function `getSalary()` that was there (in an object accessible through _ _proto_ _ ref. of `PermanentEmployee` object) before just became unaccessible. Since `getSalary()` is no longer accessible within `PermanentEmployee` object, JS tries to find it in a chain of prototypes and goes to `employee` object that doesn't have such a method nor have reference to an object with `getSalary()` method itself through its _ _proto_ _ and finally an error is thrown because `getSalary()` method isn't found anywhere.

Comment: This is quite essential, core part of Javascript and you would like to get it right from the start. I tried my best with the explanation above which is pretty accurate to my taste, but it may sound confusing to newbies, so, you should find additional material that cover this topic in more detail. That is my advice.

Comment: Well thank u sir it helped me a bit... i think i have to learn more about prototype and inhertance

Comment: So of i declare `getSalary()` method inside the constructor function will it work then.?

Comment: in your code you could put it like this: `Employee.prototype.getSalary = function()` taking this method from PermanentEmployee and adding it to Employee and it will work.

Comment: Also you should learn OOP in order to meaningfully use classes. So, it is quite unlikely to write good, working, maintainable, stable JS code without having solid notions of OOP and JS inheritance model.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the expected behavior. If you want to understand why, here we go...

Consider the following schema, available in the excellent book *[Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/index.html#toc_ch_classes)* by **Dr. Axel Rauschmayer**.

[image]

Before to go on, here is an important rule: in JavaScript, when you create an instance of a "class", this instance will reference the **prototype property** of its constructor through its **dunder proto** (`__proto__` or `[[Prototype]]`).

### Top left

In your example, `Employee` and `PermanentEmployee` are constructor functions. Like any function in JavaScript, they are instances of `Function` and they use `Function.prototype`.

```js
var Employee = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var PermanentEmployee = function(annualSalary) {
  this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
}

console.log(typeof Object.getPrototypeOf(Employee)); // ES5
console.log(typeof PermanentEmployee.__proto__); // ES6

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Employee).constructor); // ES5
console.log(PermanentEmployee.__proto__.constructor); // ES6
```

### Top right

When you write `Employee.prototype.getName` or `PermanentEmployee.prototype.getSalary`, you are actually adding new properties to the prototype property of `Employee` and `PermanentEmployee`. But `Employee.prototype` and `PermanentEmployee.prototype` are instances of `Object` and use `Object.prototype`.

```js
var Employee = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Employee.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

var PermanentEmployee = function(annualSalary) {
  this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
}

PermanentEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
  return this.annualSalary;
}

console.log(typeof Employee.prototype);
console.log(typeof PermanentEmployee.prototype);

console.log(Employee.prototype);
console.log(PermanentEmployee.prototype);
```

Since `PermanentEmployee.prototype` is a simple object, this is not reasonable to do so: `PermanentEmployee.prototype = employee`.

When you do that, **you override the prototype**. To make a basic comparison, look at this example with an object literal:

```js
var obj = {
  foo: 'Foo'
};

obj.bar = 'Bar';

console.log(obj);

obj = 'Baz';

console.log(obj);

obj = {
  foo: 'Foo',
  bar: 'Bar',
  baz: 'Baz'
};

console.log(obj);
```

You should keep this in mind when you play with prototypes...

### Bottom right

In JavaScript, there are several strategies to create a "pure" object (functions and arrays are objects too...). You can:

- Use an object literal: `{}`
- Use a constructor: `new Object()`
- Use `Object.create()`

In your example, you are using constructors. Therefore, your instances will use the prototype properties of your constructors, which themselves use the prototype property of `Object`. This is how the **prototype chain** works!

```js
var Employee = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Employee.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

var PermanentEmployee = function(annualSalary) {
  this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
}

PermanentEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
  return this.annualSalary;
}

var employee = new Employee("Mark");

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(employee)); // ES5
console.log(employee.__proto__.constructor); // ES6
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(employee))); // ES5
console.log(employee.__proto__.__proto__.constructor); // ES6
```

But of course, if you have completely overriden your prototype somewhere, you break the prototype chain and it will not work as expected...